# ios swift cannot invoke map with argument list oftype

Tags: swift, dictionary

I'm new in xCode (Swift) development and I'm trying to create the following structure:

```
struct artistSection : Comparable {
  var artist : String
  var vinyls : [Vinyl]
  var collapsed : Bool

  static func group(vinyls : [Vinyl]) -> [artistSection] {
     let groups = Dictionary(grouping : vinyls) { (vinyl) -> String in
       return (vinyl.artist!)
     }
     return groups.map(artistSection.init(artist: vinyls: collapsed:)).sorted
  }
}
```

I'm having the following error on the return.map:

> Cannot invoke 'map' with the argument list of type '((String,[Vinyl],Bool)-> VinylTableViewController.artistSection)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to supply the input arguments to the initializer of `ArtistSection` in `map`.

```
struct ArtistSection:Comparable {
    var artist : String
    var vinyls : [Vinyl]
    var collapsed : Bool

    static func group(vinyls : [Vinyl]) -> [ArtistSection] {
        let groups = Dictionary(grouping : vinyls) { (vinyl) -> String in
            return (vinyl.artist!)
        }
        return groups.map({ArtistSection(artist: $0.key, vinyls: $0.value, collapsed: false)}).sorted()
    }
}
```

Unrelated to the error, but also make sure that you conform to the Swift naming convention, which is UpperCamelCase for types (`ArtistSection` rather than `artistSection`).

Comment: Thanks so much. It worked. And thanks for the recommendation on the naming convention.